# How can I assign guake to Fn + F7?

Tags: guake

How can I assign Fn + F7 to be the Guake terminal? Currently, the shortcut is F12 but I have to use the Fn switch when I want to use brightness control. I could change brightness and use F7 both if I new how to remap Guake.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly easy.

Open up the Unity menu (you can open it via the Super/Meta/Win key) or via clicking the Ubuntu logo in the upper-left:

[image]

Then search `guake`:

[image]

And click on the `Guake Preferences` icon. It'll be different looking for you, since I use the Numix Circle icon theme, but the text will be the same:

[image]

Once it opens, select the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab and then click on the `F12` item, under the **Shortcut** label:

[image]

And you should be able to set it from there!

Comment: Could `Fn` key be used in such approach? It doesn't even respond to `xev` command.

Comment: Well, I believe it could - have you tried? If it doesn't work you can always set it back.

Comment: I basically have it set such that if I press the brightness key it changes brightness.  Therefore, to activate Guake, I have to press Fn + F12.  The F7 key does nothing, so I want to be able to see guake by pressing F7 without pressing the Fn key. Following your answer didn't work though.